# Analyzing the time complexity of this function

Tags: time-complexity

Assuming do_something is O(1), how do I calculate the time complexity of this function?

```
function run(n) {
  for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var counter = 1;
    while(counter <= n) {
        for (var j = counter; j >= 1; j--) {
             do_something();
        } 
        counter = counter * 2;
    }

  }
}
```

I'm assuming the initial for loop means the that the complexity will be n and the inner while loop means log(n). Is this true?

How do I calculate the complexity of everything? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial to calculate the complexity of everything because there are functions (e. g. collatz conjecture) where no exact analysis is known. In such a case you can do an empirical analysis where you guess which run time class would match best.

Related to your sample:

1. The outer for loop is called n times
2. The while loop is called log(n) times
3. The inner for loop is called counter times where counter grows 2^m. But counter is recalculated log(n) times

That means the inner exponential for loop (2^m) is called m=log(n) times. 
So you have 2^(log n) = n log(2) = n

You can also do it vice versa. The inner exponential function is called log times. Means log(2^m) -> (2^n = 2^m) -> m = n.

You can also simply create a sum of 2^m from m=0 to m=log(n) which is 2n-1 -> O(n).

Then you have to multiply linear time of outer for loop with linear time of while loop (incl. inner for loop). So you have O(n*n) = **O(n²)** time.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you got to the nlog(n)?

Answer (score 0):

The exact amount of steps can be calculated.

1. The outer loop runs *n* times
2. The while and inner-most loop is run *counter* times for each of the values of *counter*, these are `1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^(bitLength(n)-1)`
   which sums to `2^bitLength(n) - 1`

where `bitLength(n) = trunc(ln(n)/ln(2))+1`

Multiplying these two, yields the exact amount of steps:

`n * (2^bitLength(n) - 1)`

The approximate complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, because `O(2^bitLength(n) - 1) = O(n)`